# parsing html and following a javascript link

Tags: r, html-parsing

I have been asked to extract info by an academic colleague from a website where I need to link the content of a webpage in a table - not too hard with the contents of a text file which is only reacheable (as far as I can tell) by clicking on a javascript link... e.g.

```
<a id="tk1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('tk1$ContentPlaceHolder1$grid$tk$OpenFileButton','')">
```

The table is conveniently inside a table with id='tk1' which is nice... but how do I follow the link which pulls the text file.

Ideally I'd like to do this in R... I can grab the relevant table in text format by saying

```
u <- the url of interest...
library(XML)
tables = readHTMLTable(u)
interestingTable <- tables[grep('tk1', names(tables))]
```

And this will give the text in the table, but how do I grab the html for that particular table? and how do I "click" on the button and get the text file behind it?

I note that there is a form with massive hidden values - the site appears to be asp.net driven and uses impenetrable URLs.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is somewhat tricky, and not fully integrated in R, but some system()-fiddling will get you started.

- Download and install phantom javascript:  http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/
- Check the short script on http://menne-biomed.de/uni/JavaButton.html, which emulates your case. When you click the javascript anchor, it redirects http://cran.at.r-project.org/  via doPostBack(inaccessibleJavascriptVar).
- Save the following script locally as javabutton.js

```
var page = new WebPage();
page.open('http://www.menne-biomed.de/uni/JavaButton.html', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        var ua = page.evaluate(function () {
            var t =  document.getElementById('tk1').href;
            var re = new RegExp('\((.*)\)');
            return eval(re.exec(t)[1]);

        });
        console.log(ua);// Outputs http://cran.at.r-project.org/
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

- With phantomjs on path, call

  phantomjs javabutton.js

The link will be displayed on the console. Use any method to get it into Rcurl.

Not elegant, but maybe someones wraps phantomjs into R one day. In case the link to JaveButton.html should be lost, here it is as code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
<script>
inaccesibleJavascriptVar = 'http://' + 'cran.at.r-project.org/';
function doPostBack(myref)
          {
            window.location.href= myref;
            return false;
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="tk1" href="javascript:doPostBack(inaccesibleJavascriptVar)" >Click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the RCurl package:

http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/

Comment: Thanks Dieter, I was aware of RCurl and I've used it and its' cookiejar but I can't see how I can get it can follow javascript button links - can it?

Comment: No, that was a bad idea of mine: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Does_curl_support_Javascript_or